# How to emulate an XBox 360 controller on Windows 10 apps?

Tags: controllers

I am aware about the x360emu program. I know how it works, I managed to set it up with my games. The problem is that I want to use my controllers with Windows 10 apps (in my case: Forza Horizon 3). The game works fine if the controller itself is a XBox Controller, or uses XInput (in my case: Genesys PV59 Wireless Controller).

How can I emulate an XBox 360 controller to work with Windows 10 apps such as Forza Horizon 3 ?

I have tried to copy the program with the dll-s in the game directory (the game is installed on another hard drive, that's why I can access the game files) but failed because the whole directory is protected.

I have tried to use HookMode=3 in x360emu config file to no success.